# MySQL multiple rows with same id meeting two different conditions at same time

Tags: mysql

I am using OTRS helpdesk ticket management system. When i execute following Query:

```
SELECT  `ticket`.`id` ,  `ticket_history`.`ticket_id` ,  `ticket_history`.`id` ,
`ticket_history`.`name` ,  `ticket_history`.`create_time` 
FROM  `ticket_history` 
INNER JOIN  `ticket` ON  `ticket_history`.`ticket_id` =  `ticket`.`id` 
WHERE  `ticket_history`.`name` LIKE  '%Raw% %new%'
OR  `ticket_history`.`name` LIKE  '%Close'
ORDER BY  `ticket_history`.`ticket_id` ,  `ticket_history`.`id` ASC
```

I get the following output:

```
+----+-----------+-----+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id | ticket_id | id  |                   name                    |     create_time     |
+----+-----------+-----+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         1 |  79 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-10 11:50:33 |
|  2 |         2 |   2 | %%2013060810000011%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%2 | 2013-06-08 21:59:02 |
|  3 |         3 |   5 | %%2013060810000021%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%3 | 2013-06-08 21:59:03 |
|  3 |         3 |  22 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-08 22:10:41 |
|  3 |         3 |  82 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-10 11:50:49 |
|  4 |         4 |  88 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-10 11:51:32 |
|  5 |         5 |  64 | %%2013060910000019%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%5 | 2013-06-09 17:12:09 |
|  5 |         5 |  85 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-10 11:51:10 |
|  6 |         6 |  92 | %%2013061010000016%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%6 | 2013-06-10 12:00:24 |
|  7 |         7 |  95 | %%2013061010000025%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%7 | 2013-06-10 13:05:05 |
|  8 |         8 |  98 | %%2013061110000014%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%8 | 2013-06-11 19:05:06 |
|  8 |         8 | 109 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-17 23:57:35 |
|  9 |         9 | 163 | %%2013061810000011%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%9 | 2013-06-18 02:05:06 |
+----+-----------+-----+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

I need to modify the above query so I can only list rows of each ticket_id which has "%RAW% %new%" in name and at the same time same ticket_id has a row which has "%Close" in it.

In other words, Three rows of ticket_id 3, Two rows of ticket_id 5 and Two Rows of ticket_id  8 should be displayed from the above output.

Comment: I am new to Stackoverflow. How do i paste the sql output so it is shown properly as a table.

Comment: You can use `<pre>` for that.

Comment: Can you take any further steps towards normalizing your data? Also, given that ticket.id and ticket_history.ticket_id are always equal what's the point of selecting both columns and ordering by both columns? Daft, right?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT `ticket`.`id` ,  `ticket_history`.`ticket_id` ,  `ticket_history`.`id` ,`ticket_history`.`name` ,  `ticket_history`.`create_time`
FROM tickets t INNER JOIN ticket_history th
ON t.ticket_id = th.ticket_id
WHERE
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ticket_history WHERE name LIKE '%Raw% %new%' AND ticket_id = t.ticket_id)
AND
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ticket_history WHERE name LIKE '%Close' AND ticket_id = t.ticket_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a simple `OR` to check for something that you don't want in the result set.  My first guess would be a correlated subquery.  Might not perform especially well, but it should work.  Maybe something like this (off the top of my head and totally untested):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ticket_history AS th INNER JOIN ticket ON ticket_history.ticket_id = ticket.id
WHERE ticket_history.name LIKE '%Raw% %new%' 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ticket_history WHERE name LIKE '%Close' AND ticket_id = th.ticket_id)
```

Comment: Hi Peter,Your query is giving me following error : #1054 - Unknown column 'ticket_history.ticket_id' in 'field list'

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see I forgot to change the FROM clause to use an alias.  That should be `FROM ticket_history AS th INNER JOIN ticket ON th.ticket_id = ticket.id`.  Like I said, completely untested.

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't duplicate rows. You asked for ticket history records that meet a condition, along with their tickets. The first ID is the ticket id. The second ID is the ticket history ID. Because there are multiple ticket history entries for each ticket, you are getting multiple records. I might try (but have not tested):

```
SELECT  `ticket`.`id` 
FROM  `ticket` 
INNER JOIN  `ticket_history` t1 ON  t1.`ticket_id` =  `ticket`.`id` AND t1.`name` LIKE  '%Raw% %new%' 
INNER JOIN `ticket_history` t2 ON t2.ticket_id = ticket.id AND  t2.`name` LIKE  '%Close' 
ORDER BY  ticket.id ASC
```

I removed the ticket_history fields from the select because there's no way to get those without multiple records, since you're essentially asking for ticket records that match two ticket history records.

Comment: Hi Davidfuber,I understand that those are duplicate entries. I need both rows of each ticket_id which contains a row for '%Raw% %new%' and another row for '%Close'

Comment: Hi Davidfuber, Your solution is closest i have come to achieve my objective. Now only thing i need is to show the other columns from Ticket_history table and a row for %RAW% %new% and a row for %Close for each ticket which fits in the criteria.

Comment: how about add some fields to the select: SELECT ticket.id, t1.name AS t1_name, t1.created AS t1.created, t2.name AS t2_name, t2.created AS t2_created.

Answer (score 1):

I have no way to test this right now, but I think this might work:

```
SELECT  `ticket`.`id` ,  `ticket_history`.`ticket_id` ,  `ticket_history`.`id` ,
`ticket_history`.`name` ,  `ticket_history`.`create_time` 
FROM  `ticket_history` 
INNER JOIN  `ticket` ON  `ticket_history`.`ticket_id` =  `ticket`.`id` 
WHERE  `ticket`.`id` IN (SELECT `ticket`.`id` FROM `ticket_history`
                       WHERE  `ticket_history`.`name` LIKE  '%Raw% %new%')
ORDER BY  `ticket_history`.`ticket_id` ,  `ticket_history`.`id` ASC
```

Comment: Hi Waka, Your query gives back the rows containing '%Raw% %new%'. The rows with %Close are not shown.

Comment: Oh yeah, right. They aren't because I only filter for those rows that contain "%Raw% %new%". If I can't come up with a better solution until tomorrow, I'm deleting this post to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Finally this is the right solution which I built from your suggestions and help from few other internet links .. Thanks all for your help.

```
SELECT `ticket`.`id`, `th`.`ticket_id`, `th`.`id`, `th`.`name`,  `th`.`create_time`    
FROM `ticket_history` th   JOIN `ticket` ON  `th`.`ticket_id` =  `ticket`.`id`   WHERE (
            `th`.`name` LIKE  '%Raw% %new%'
            AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ticket_history th1 WHERE th1.ticket_id = ticket.id AND th1.name LIKE '%Close')
           )
        OR (
            `th`.`name` LIKE  '%Close'
            AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ticket_history th2 WHERE th2.ticket_id = ticket.id AND th2.name LIKE '%Raw% %new%')
           )  ORDER BY th.ticket_id, th.id ASC;
```